# kotlin: list properties of any object - variance error

Tags: kotlin, covariance

I'm trying to write a function that produces map of properties and values for any type

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> T.propertiesMap() {
    for (property in this::class.memberProperties) {
        property.get(this)
    }
}
```

i get a compilation error in `property.get(this)` about

> out-projected type [...] prohibits the use of 'public abstract fun get(receiver...

Comment: Besides the question you have, you do not need to reify the type nor make the function inline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `this::class` produces a `KClass<out T>` instead of `KClass<T>` which is what would be needed to use anything of type `T` in the `property.get(...)` call.  So you can do an unchecked cast to do what you want:

```
fun <T : Any> T.propertiesMap() {
    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    for (property in (this::class as KClass<T>).memberProperties) {
        property.get(this)
    }
}
```

Which does not require the function to be inline nor reified type parameter.  Otherwise you can change your function to use `T::class` instead of `this::class` to create a matching `KClass<T>`.

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> T.propertiesMap() {
    for (property in T::class.memberProperties) {
        property.get(this)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the type you are reifying rather than an instance of that type the variance issue will go away. When you call `T::class.memberProperties` you get back a `Collection<KProperty<T, *>>` which is what I believe you want. On the other hand, if you call that on an instance (`this`) rather than a type, you get back a `Collection<KProperty<out T, Any?>>`, which is where your out-variance issue comes from.

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> T.propertiesMap() {
    for (property in T::class.memberProperties) {
        property.get(this)
    }
}
```

Essentially, you need to do `T::class` rather than `this::class` in order to get the right kind of collection back. I've left your code as-is otherwise because I'm not clear on what you want this function to do, but I suspect you could drop the for loop in favor of a `map` call.